# Jumping into webdev. Want to make a very simple mp3 player with play/pause and volume slider. Which tech do I need to learn?

Tags: html, web

I've got a webpage in mind that I'd like to make. Aside from HTML and CSS, what else do I need to learn if I want to make a very basic audio player? Basically, like I mentioned, I just want to be able to have a play/stop button, and a volume slider.

What tools do I need to learn? Is JavaScript something that would do this, or can all of this be done with HTML5 now (I don't know what exactly html5 actually means).

Comment: For webdevelopment in general, probably in most of the cases. For this specific example, HTML5 suffices.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe can definitely be done with HTML5. [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />

</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Honestly though, if you don't know what HTML5 (or just HTML even) actually means, you should probably find a tutorial that explains the **very** basics of webdevelopment.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. I'll read up on this now. This is something I'll make and then probably never touch again, so I was looking for the simplest implementation possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with html auto controls tag but that's not really fun or challenging... JavaScript for interactive controlling functions, CSS for styling the controls, and html to link in the audio. You can even make it more fun by adding some JQUERY file control and drag and drop uploads and CSS html color changer to let users make a custom music player with sharing capabilities. The possibilities are endless c: sorry if that's a bit much but you can do much more with JS and CSS than just with HTML audio tags. There are tons of things to learn.